# Cleanup and merge the scattered tags about encryption/decryption?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-creation

While editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078692/how-to-decipher-a-text), I have noticed how scattered the tags related to encryption / decryption have become.

Here are my suggestions for some of the main tags and their outcasts that I have noticed:

1. Merge [encrypted](/questions/tagged/encrypted) into [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption).
2. Merge [ciphers](/questions/tagged/ciphers) into [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher).
3. Create a new tag [decryption](/questions/tagged/decryption) and merge [decrypt](/questions/tagged/decrypt) and [decipher](/questions/tagged/decipher) into it.

How about doing this cleanup, and merging the outcasts into the existing or newly-created proper tags?

Comment: [`Decryption` is already a synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/synonyms) of `encryption`.

Comment: Doesn't [tag:decryption] differ a lot from [tag:encryption]? I mean, although there is a common theme between both, but far from synonyms, one is the **opposite** of the other! ___ I'll use a famous misquotation here: *"Houston, we have a problem!"*

Comment: Well yes, we would hope that decryption would be **qualitatively** different from encryption -- or else our bank accounts and porn stashes are doomed!  But I didn't make or vote to approve that synonym.

Comment: You might not have voted or approved the synonym, but you can help fix the problem that it configures! - For our porn stash's sake! =P